# Merge nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an XML file with the following pattern: nodes with the **ref** property have the same value as the **id** property of other nodes.
This is a visual example in Neo4j:

[image: Sample data set]

The yellow one has the ref property (ref=2) value as *TWO* (id=2).

My goal is to create a graph, deleting each node with the ref value that is equal to other id nodes, but also preserving the relationship *isFatherOf* that has to point to the other node, in this case, *TWO*.

Here is the outcome of the procedure:

[image: Desired output]

I'm able to delete all the ref nodes with the following procedure,

```
match (n1:Node)
with collect(distinct n1.id) as ids 
collection called 'ids'
match (n2:Node)
where n2.ref in ids
detach delete n2
```

but I do not know how to preserve the relationships. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your scenario using this sample data model:

```
create (one:Node {id : 1, name : 'ONE'}),
    (two:Node {id : 2, name : 'TWO'}),
    (ref:Node {ref:2}),
    (one)-[:isFatherOf]->(ref)
```

The following Cypher query should do the work:

```
// get all 'n1' nodes point to an node with 'ref' property
match (n1:Node)-[r:isFatherOf]->(refNode:Node)
where exists(refNode.ref)
// match 'n2' nodes that have an ID equal to 'n2.ref'
match (n2:Node {id : refNode.ref})
// create a new relationship between 'n1' and 'n2'
create (n1)-[:isFatherOf]->(n2)
// remove node with 'ref' properties and all relationships
detach delete refNode
```

For the sample data set the output will be:

[image: Output]

If you need to preserve the original relationship instead of creating a brand new one, then you will need to use the [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_help_and_usage) `apoc.refactor.to`. This procedure redirects the relationship to use new end-node.

```
match (n1:Node)-[r:isFatherOf]->(refNode:Node)
where exists(refNode.ref)
match (n2:Node {id : refNode.ref})
// redirecting 'r' to use 'n2' as end node
call apoc.refactor.to(r, n2) yield output
delete refNode
```

The output will be the same.